# OpenSSL -DPURIFY problem

Tags: 14.04, openssl

I tried to recompile `openssl` with `flag -DPURIFY` using [this guide][1]. However when I try to install the package using `sudo debi`, I get following error:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 is not a symbolic link
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 is not a symbolic link
```

How to fix it?
I use Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Release: 14.04)

[Link](https://gist.github.com/mpenick/9bd0707096dd8dc64996)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh, problem solved - there were two identical files for `libssl` and `libcrypto` with different names. Removing one of them solved the problem.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I am sorry I don't remember details anymore.